# Can't call angular2 function to javascript function

Tags: javascript, angular

i've two function , 1.angular2function 2.javascriptfunction.
below is my example code :

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onBeforeEventChanged", function(ev, e, is_new, original){
this.getdata(); 
}); // this is javascript function

public getdata(){
.....
} // this is angular2 function
```

But there is an error = this.getdata(); is not a function.
How to fix it?

Comment: is this a part of angular1 or 2??have u declared this??

Comment: What Angular version is this about? For `this.getdata();` to work you probably need to change `function(ev, e, is_new, original)` to `(ev, e, is_new, original) => `

Comment: thank you @GünterZöchbauer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` inside your callback function doesn't point to the class instance anymore. The easy fix would be to use arrow function instead of a "classic" one:

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onBeforeEventChanged", (ev, e, is_new, original) => {
    this.getdata(); 
}); // this is javascript function

public getdata(){
    .....
}
```

You can read more on how `this` behaves in various situation - and dow to deal with it on [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context)